# How do I automatically disable touchpad while typing or while a mouse is plugged in on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10

I looked around and found touchpad-indicator, but when I go through everything and install it, my computer doesn't recognize it. I did some more googling and it seems like touchpad-indicator doesn't work past 14.04. Is it possible for me to have automatic disabling/enabling of my touchpad in 15.10?